# How can I troubleshoot when an iPad no longer charges an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, charging, ipados

I found that my iPhone is no longer being charged from my iPad, both of which are connected via USB-C to Magsafe cable. In the past, whenever I lost the battery of my iPhone (or AirPods Pro), I just connected it to my iPad via cable (though not Magsafe) and the battery of iPad was drained into the iPhone.

- 11-inch iPad Pro (2020)
- iPhone 14 Pro (2022)

Is this something that Apple changed or is there anything other that I’m missing here?

Comment: What if you go directly USB-C to USB-C? The only wireless charging referenced is the Apple Watch.  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209186

Comment: Works here with an iPad Pro (12.9 inch)(4th generation) and an iPhone 11 Pro , both on iOS 16.5.1, connected via USB-C from iPad to USB-A adapter to lightning on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Allan suggested in the comment using [the link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209186), surprisingly(!) you cannot charge your iPhone from iPad using MagSafe connector.